# Replace a file temporarily during an sh script run

Tags: linux, sh

I use an sh script to start an application in the background after setting several environment variables. I use temporary variables to start binaries from different places using LD_LIBRARY_PATH and temporary variables. Problem is that the application loads one *.so file from a hardcoded path which I cannot change. Currently I solve this problem manually by replacing the hardcoded file location with a symbolic link.

Can you tell me if there is a clean solution to solve this from the sh script? Basically what I want is that a certain file location is switched with a different binary only for open calls from the application the script starts, for all other processes it should stay the same.

Regards.

Comment: After `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set, can you run `ldd your-application`, post the output, and specify the one `.so` of interest?  The 2nd paragraph in the original posting is unclear (_file location_, _different binary_),  can you elaborate? Guessing: for one application, do you want to replace `open("/original/file",,)` with `open("/some/other/file",,)` ?

Comment: Exactly. open("/original/file",,) should be interpreted as open("/some/other/file",,) for this one process and transparent to it.

Comment: Perhaps you could `chroot` yout process into a specially prepared environment. (Mind you, those who find chroot hard use containers.)

Answer (score 0):

Example methods to replace `open("/the/original")` with `open("/some/other")`:

One simple method is modifying a pathname within an executable.
First copy the original executable to something like "modified" and run
a utility like [bvi](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+bvi) (similar to `vim`).
Consider 2 cases from comparing the length of the new vs. original pathnames:

- when (new-length <= original-length), overwrite the original pathname in place
- when (new-length > original-length), create a short symlink that references
  the new longer pathname like the example below, then overwrite the original pathname
  with the short symlink pathname,

  `ln -s /full/path/some/new/file /shorter`

For both cases, remember to include a trailing NULL byte.
After saving changes with `bvi`, test the newly copied+altered executable.
Once "modified" is working to plan, could also rename for convenience:

`mv xyz xyz.orig`
`mv modified xyz`

---

Another method can serve a transparency requirement.
Create a dynamic library (eg `custom.so`) with a wrapper routine for
`open()` which conditionally replaces the pathname and calls the real
libc `open()`.  Run the unmodified original executable (xyz) with another
environment variable, eg:

`LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/custom.so xyz`

There are some tradeoffs with versatility and modest complexity;
the original xyz is left unchanged and can always be run with/without `LD_PRELOAD`;
some might consider added overhead from a wrapper as undesirable;
doesn't work with statically-linked or set-uid executables.

Many articles provide instructions for creating a preload library, re-using
an original symbol like `open()` (frequent example is `malloc()`), call `dlsym()` once to find the regular libc `open()`, saving the result as a function pointer, and calling libc `open()` indirectly.